# Deriving the solutions of a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Let $K\in \mathbb{N}$ with $K\geq 2$ and consider the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^h y_j *x_{K+j-h}=\sum_{j=1}^h x_j *y_{K+j-h} & \text{ for }h=1,...,K-1\\
\sum_{j=1}^Ky_j=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
that is 
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1*x_K=x_1*y_K\\
y_1*x_{K-1}+y_2*x_K=x_1*y_{K-1}+x_2*y_K\\
y_1*x_{K-2}+y_2*x_{K-1}+y_3*x_K=x_1*y_{K-2}+x_2*y_{K-1}+x_3*y_K\\
...\\
y_1*x_2+y_2*x_3+...+y_{K-1}*x_K=x_1*y_2+x_2*y_3+...+x_{K-1}*y_K\\
y_1+y_2+...+y_K=1\\
\end{cases}
$$

For example, when $K=3$, the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1*x_3=x_1*y_3\\
y_1*x_2+y_2*x_3=x_1*y_2+x_2*y_3\\
y_1+y_2+y_3=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
**Note:**

- The unknowns of the system are $y_1,...,y_K$, while $x_1,...,x_K$ are treated as parameters.
- I assume that $y_j>0,x_j>0$ for $j=1,...,K$.
- We know that the parameters $x_1,...,x_K$ are such that $\sum_{j=1}^K x_j=1$

  ---

**Question:** I want to show that the solutions of the system above are
$$
\begin{cases}
(a) \text{ }y_j=x_j & \text{  for }j=1,...,K\\
\text{or }\\
(b) \text{ }y_j=y_{K+1-j} & \text{ for }j=1,...,\lfloor\frac{K+1}{2} \rfloor
\end{cases}
$$
where $\lfloor A \rfloor$ denotes the the largest integer less than or equal to $A$.

---

**What I have tried (incomplete):** I have the proof when $K=3$ (very simple).

$$
\begin{cases}
y_1*x_3=x_1*y_3\\
y_1*x_2+y_2*x_3=x_1*y_2+x_2*y_3\\
y_1+y_2+y_3=1\\
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\frac{x_3}{x_1}=\frac{y_3}{y_1}\\
\frac{x_2}{x_1}+\frac{y_2}{y_1}\frac{x_3}{x_1}=\frac{y_2}{y_1}+\frac{y_3}{y_1}\frac{x_2}{x_1} 
\end{cases}
$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x_2}{x_1}+\frac{y_2}{y_1}\frac{y_3}{y_1}=\frac{y_2}{y_1}+\frac{y_3}{y_1}\frac{x_2}{x_1}\Leftrightarrow \Big( \frac{y_2}{y_1}-\frac{x_2}{x_1}\Big)\Big(\frac{y_3}{y_1}-1 \Big)=0
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \text{ }y_3=y_1 \text{ or } \frac{y_2}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{x_1}
$$

If $y_3=y_1$ then we are in case (b) of the general claim above.

If $ \frac{y_2}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{x_1}$, then the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{y_3}{y_1}=\frac{x_3}{x_1}\\
\frac{y_2}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{x_1}\\
y_1+y_2+y_3=1\\
\end{cases} \Rightarrow y_1+\frac{x_2}{x_1}y_1+\frac{x_3}{x_1}y_1=1
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow y_1(\frac{\overbrace{x_1+x_2+x_3}^{=1}}{x_1})=1 \Leftrightarrow y_1=x_1 \Rightarrow y_3=x_3, y_2=x_2
$$
that is case (a) of the general claim above. I am struggling to generalise this to any $K$ because I'm very weak in linear algebra. Any help from your side would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you interested in this question?

Comment: It is part of a proof I have to develop.

Comment: (b) is not a solution to your system, but just a symmetry that your system exhibits. If you know half the $y$ values, it will tell you the other half, but it doesn't tell you that first half.

Comment: You can show easily that $y_i = x_i$ for all $i$ is a solution. If you can prove that your $K$ equations in the $K$ unknowns are all independent (none is a linear combination of the others), then it is the only solution, so you are done.